# Forward slash in Gitignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

I came across a very weird thing about gitignore files that they happen to use forward slash for denoting a particular directory

```
Project/module1/cppfiles
```

Rather than the usual backslash normally used in command prompt  for denoting a particular directory.

```
Project\module1\cppfiles
```

Is this completely syntactical or it has some reason behind it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I soonly found a windows documentation, compare [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/ignore-files?view=vsts#use-gitignore-to-prevent-tracking-of-files), which tells:

```
Windows users: All file paths in the .gitignore file use a forward slash separator and not a backslash.
```

git uses forward slashes in the `.gitignore` for compatibility with unix syntax, where you separate folders by forward and not by backward slash. This probably is related to two things:

1. git mostly is running on linux servers, so this must not be catched on server side, only on client side
2. (probably) a lot of the people using git are using unixoid systems, therefore only a few are using backward slashes - only few people have to change behaviour to work *together* with all others

Answer (score 5):

It's because Git was originally written to run on Linux, and the `/` is the path separator for Linux.

The forward-slash paths will work fine in Windows.  In fact, in many places in Windows, if you type your paths with forward slashes, it'll correct them for you automatically.